# DBD-mysql error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set

Tags: mysql, perl, gcc, dbd, cc

I am installing DBD-mysql-4.020 perl module on 5.14.2.

when running make, I encounter the below error:

cc -c  -I/u01/app/appadmin/product/perl-5.14.2/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/auto/DBI -I/usr/local/mysql-standard-4.1.14-pc-linux-gnu-i686/include -mtune=pentiumpro -DDBD_MYSQL_INSERT_ID_IS_GOOD -g  -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2   -DVERSION=\"4.020\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.020\" -fPIC "-I/u01/app/appadmin/product/perl-5.14.2/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/CORE"   dbdimp.c
dbdimp.c:1: error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set
make: *** [dbdimp.o] Error 1

upgraded compiler to gcc4.4 and did put a lot of effort to overcome this. Your inputs in resolving this and installing the perl Module are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The output of `perl -V` (uppercase "V") might be useful.

Comment: Is `-mtune=pentiumpro` appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

> error: CPU you selected does not support x86-64 instruction set make:

Does this machine have a 64-bit CPU?

If so, have you checked to see if you have 64 bit versions of perl and mysql?  Or you can you the 'lazy' route and just try installing a 32 bit version of DBD-mysql and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, my machine has a 64-bit cpu and the there is just one perl-module for both 32-bit and 64-bit. I assume the Perl module is the same for both 32-bit and 64-bit machines.